# confused in creating a SQL relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I would like to create a db on grammar. Please have a look at some of the points I think is required:

1. Each word has its own part of speech, and some of its related word (like its past tense, synonyms, etc).
2. Each part of speech, is eventually a word (like noun, adjective).
3. Each related word of the words will also be a word.

How do I create a SQL table with this relationship? Do I have to create a manytomany relationship with itself? Please help me solve this. I will be much grateful. Thank you.

**Update**

Or create different tables and then link them together, as in the picture.

[image]

**Update**

What I want is to be like this:

[image]

Comment: http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php has a good walk through of designing out the need for many to many relationships in a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to split it in to different tables.
So you have one for your words, speech, related words etc.
Would also recommend to use the word table as the main table and in the other tables add the ID of the word table to link it to each other. That way your many-to-many problem should be solved.
If I understood your question correctly this should work, if not please let me know.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the suggestion. I have updated my question, with a picture. Please have a look at it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't seem to see a picture neither a updated question? EDIT: Now it is there, however I'm afraid it is impossible for me to read the text. (This could be the problem of the computer I'm using at the moment)

Comment: Ok. Is this how you would suggest me to do?

Comment: That is almost what I suggested indeed. But I would recommend adding ID's so instead of linking the tables together with the TEXT value use a unique ID (PK) to link them. And I'm not sure if you really need an intersection entity?

Comment: Ok. I didn't wanted to repeat the text and have it as unique. Is there any reason as to why id will better than text. And also I have updated my question as to how I would want it to be. Please have a look at it. Thank you once again.

Comment: For the ID field you can use an auto increment so you are sure all values are unique. Other than that if you have lets say 2 words that are written the same but have a different meaning and different synonyms you can't do that when your PK is a text field but you can do it if you use a numeric auto increment. For the last picture: I'm afraid I don't exaclty understand what it says right there.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I don't think your design is very good at all.  You should be ideally joining on an integer rather than text fields, your naming is inconsistent so it isn't obvious which fields join together and I don't think all those tables are necessary as there seems to be a lot of duplication.

Why not go for something simple, e.g. if you want to store relations between words you only need two or three tables (this is pseudo code as I don't know which db you are targeting):

```
CREATE TABLE [Words] ([WordId] INT, [Word] TEXT);
CREATE TABLE [WordRelationships] ([WordId] INT, [RelatedWordId] INT, [RelationshipId] INT);
CREATE TABLE [Relationships] ([RelationshipId] INT, RelationshipName TEXT);
INSERT INTO Words VALUES (1, 'Mouse');
INSERT INTO Words VALUES (2, 'Cat');
INSERT INTO Relationships VALUES (1, 'Animal');
INSERT INTO WordRelationships VALUES (1, 2, 1);
etc..
```

You could then extend this, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE [Words] ADD COLUMN [WordTypeId] INT;
CREATE TABLE [WordTypes] ([WordTypeId] INT, [WordTypeName] TEXT);
INSERT INTO WordTypes VALUES (1, 'Noun');
UPDATE Words SET WordTypeId = 1 WHERE Word = 'Mouse';
etc...
```

Comment: Hello. I didn't quite understood. Could you please elaborate little more. And also I have updated my question as to how I want it to be like. Please kindly have a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: I see lots of arrows and boxes, no idea what it means though, sorry :|